# Using the same DbContext object across different controllers

Tags: c#, controller, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application & have a question in regards to using the same instantiated `DbContext` object across different controllers.

I am wanting to do this because i am retrieving some of the same data in different controllers, & the inbuilt caching feature of the `DbContext` class will minimize many database transactions.

Here is some code to explain:

```
public class TestController1 : Controller
{
    private CanFindLocationDatabaseContext db = new CanFindLocationDatabaseContext();
}

public class TestController2 : Controller
{
    private CanFindLocationDatabaseContext db = new CanFindLocationDatabaseContext();
}
```

What would be the best way to code this and are there any disadvantages to this? Should each user have their own DbContext object, or only one for all users? What should I be aware of before coding this? Could potential conflicts occur when CRUD actions occur?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not have the same dbContext for all controllers. It is not a good practice to do so because that way the framework has to track a lot more entities and if something goes wrong on EF side, it will be difficult to debug too.
Use one dbContext per controller class.

Comment: No, that's not true. If you use Dependency Injection/Inversion of Control with a PerRequestLifetimeManager, you set up one context for all your controllers, but it's created and destroyed for each request. In effect, you get one instance per controller, but you only need to do the setup once when you configure your unity container.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you ,If this what you are asking or i can understand.
You can create a BaseController where you can create DbContext instance. After that you can inherit this Basecontroller in every Controller.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
  public BaseController()
  {
     CanFindLocationDatabaseContext db = new CanFindLocationDatabaseContext();
  }
}
```

Now inherit it in all controllers like this:

```
public class YourController:BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Hello()
    {
      //us your db instance here now
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you can achieve this by doing the same. Inheriting a basecontroller in all controllers. Or sorry, i am unable to understand the question properly.

Comment: That will still create an instance per controller and not share a common one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a class as wrapper and put a static reference to the dbcontext.